# CLLocationManager prompt is displaying alert then disappearing

Tags: iphone, ios5, cllocationmanager, cllocation, alassetslibrary

This is one awful bug. When using CLLocationManger, either with startUpdatingLocation or with ALAsset methods to access metadata for a photo, the system is prompting for location access as expected...but the prompt disappears as soon as it's shown. I cannot find the reason for this and am hoping someone else has had this problem. This does not occur with other alerts (such as showing a UIAlertView).

I can even set the purpose property, and it displays, but again, only for a moment then it just closes itself.

This is a big issue for me as I require permission in order to use photo metadata.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888896/current-location-permission-dialog-disappears-too-quickly/9474095#9474095

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, now the issue appears to be resolved. And I don't know why or how.

Comment: I'm also having this problem, if anyone is able to help :)

Comment: @AndreiStoleru I added an answer that might help you

Answer (score 6):

Are you creating the CLLocationManager instance in a method like so:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

If so, then as soon as the function exits, the local locationManager variable is being cleaned up. You should save a reference to the locationManager either on an instance or in a static variable:

```
static CLLocationManager *locationManager;
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```