# Alert window that asks for permission to use current location in iOS app does not give user a chance to choose between "don't allow" and "OK"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, cllocationmanager

I am new to objective-c and iOS programming and have been trying to setup this gps/location app from scratch for the past 3 hours using xcode 5 and an iOS7 iPhone. So far the app successfully loads on my iphone. The user interface has an empty label and a button. When I tap the button, it says "YourGPSApp would like to use your current location" and then has a "Don't allow" and an "OK" option.

However, the window goes away before you can even select one of the options. I need the window to stay and let the user select an option.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Created a property for IBOutlet UILabel object in the header file and connected it with the user interface.
2. Defined an IBAction method in the header file and connected it with the button on the UI.

This is the final result in my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *gpsLabel;

-(IBAction)gpsButton;

@end
```

And then I edited the main file and ended up with this source code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(IBAction)gpsButton
{

CLLocationManager * gpsLM = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

[gpsLM startUpdatingLocation];

}
@end
```

At this point I am 99% sure that when I tap the gpsButton that I setup in the header that it is successfully asking the user's iPhone what it's location is because I get the window alert asking if I would like to allow it to see my location.

I also went to my iPhone settings and manually turned on location services for this app. Then I went back to the app screen and pressed the button again and it shows the "finding location" arrow next to the batter up in the top right of the iPhone screen and also displays the same arrow next to my app's name when I go back to my iPhone's location settings.

This tells me that my "location finding" methods are working correctly.

I just really need to figure out how to keep the window from disappearing so the user can select "Don't Allow" or "OK".

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888896/current-location-permission-dialog-disappears-too-quickly)

the reason is the CLLocationManager is released before you can confirm the choice.

you should set the CLLocationManager as a member, or the ARC will release the object, so the window is dismissed automatically.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager * gpsLM;


-(IBAction)gpsButton
{

self.gpsLM = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];  // you may like the alloc it in the init method

[self.gpsLM startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! It now lets me select an option and then the window disappears correctly once you choose. Some quick questions though. 1. Why does the property statement need IBOutlet? 2. In the object initializer statement, how come you are able to type "self.gpsLM = " instead of "CLLocationManager *gpsLM = " like you normally would?

Comment: "IBOutlet" is i copied your code and forget to delete it :),  and you should learn how to use ARC the manager the object's lifecycle

Comment: Will I learn the answer to this question if I learn more about ARC the manager of the object's lifecycle: 2. In the object initializer statement, how come you are able to type "self.gpsLM = " instead of "CLLocationManager *gpsLM = " like you normally would? Is that what you mean?

Comment: i mean you don't have to alloc the CLLocationManager every time you tap the button, only once is enough

Comment: Ok I understand. It sounds like a better way to do this would be to move the method implementation up into viewDidLoad's code block. This initializes it when the app first loads. I just tested it and it works perfectly. Is that the type of solution that would be better?

Comment: both works, but vieDidLoad use to create UIViews, but not members