# Location services permission alert disappears too quickly

Tags: ios, xcode, cllocationmanager, class-variables

I'm having the same problem as posted here:
[Current location permission dialog disappears too quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888896/current-location-permission-dialog-disappears-too-quickly/9474095#9474095)

I tried following the first answer which seems to have worked for everyone else, but I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I don't think I'm using class-level instance variables properly.

**header file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface whatever : NSObject     <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

+ (CLLocationManager *)locationManager;

@end
```

**implementation file**

```
//#import header file
@interface whatever()

@property CLLocationManager *locationManager;

+ (CLLocationManager *)locationManager;

@end

@implementation whatever

+ (CLLocationManager *)locationManager;
{
    static CLLocationManager *locationM = nil;
    if(locationM == nil)
    {
        locationM = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }
    return locationM;
}

- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        self.locationManager = [whatever locationManager];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;     
    }
     return self;
}
- (void)myMethod
{
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

Comment: try to change from this `@property CLLocationManager *locationManager;` in this `@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;` If still not working try to make `strong` your shared instance from your ViewController

Comment: it was the answer. I had to tweak a few things, but adding `strong` solved the problem.