# How to handle "Turn ON Location Alert" on Calendar App, Its an iOS issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8.3

Steps to produce this issue of iOS Calendar App.
(for this issue you must have already 'Allow' location service for calendar app)

1) Go To Settings
2) Turn Off Location services
3) Go To Calendar App
4) Add New Event
5) Select Location to enter
You will see "Turn ON Location Services To Allow....." Alert 
with "Settings" and "Cancel" buttons. But alert will get disappear in 1-2 seconds and app displays Location search screen.

How to handle this event? Or is there any solution for this case?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  It doesn't appear to be about programming.

Comment: @Droppy, Please follow steps. I just want to confirm , is it iOS issue and can we handle it ?

Comment: Isn't this an issue in an Apple app?  What's it got to do with programming, or are you saying the same issue happens in your own apps?

Comment: I am using EKEventEditViewController to add an event to calendar.
but if you try to enter location when "Location Services" are OFF. 
its shows and alert "Turn ON Location Services To Allow....." for 1-2 sec. so not able to go to settings to turn it ON.

Comment: I doubt there is anything you can do about it.  It sounds like an bug in the O/S.

Comment: yes, its a bug in O/S. i thought someone had handle or did anything else which i don't know.  :) I must post this to Apple's forum

Comment: @RohitWankhede have you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888896/current-location-permission-dialog-disappears-too-quickly)