# Alert for permission of location service in iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cllocationmanager

I have set the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in `info.plist`, the alert appears when the app wants to use the location service, but the alert just appear for a little time and I can't click on this alert. This alert disappear automatically！

```
 func showLocation(sender: UIButton)
    {
        let manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways
        {
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        for location in locations {
            print("The location is (location)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this step by step, and see if you are using it right. http://matthewfecher.com/app-developement/getting-gps-location-using-core-location-in-ios-8-vs-ios-7/

Comment: are used in this line anywhere on your method `alertView.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, animated: true)`

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: It is a little test demo for CLLocationManager. When I click on a button, one action is invoked. In this action I create the instance of CLLocationManager and ask the user for permission. There is supposed to be a alert for permission, yes there is. But the alert disappear atomically disappear without my click. This my first time to use stack overflow and my English is not bad. I don't know if my expression is correct, I am sorry. And Thank you for your answer!

Comment: There is no code about the alert, this alert appear when the method requestWhenInUseAuthorization() is called. And then this alert disappear quickly@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: The answer: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888896/current-location-permission-dialog-disappears-too-quickly/9474095#9474095

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
{
    if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"] && [self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]){
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
}
else if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
{
    //Location Services is off from settings

}
else if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
{

}
```

Try Following code. It worked for me

Comment: You are right, the instance of CLLocationManager must be class level. And thank you for your  framework to write the code.

Comment: M grateful for being able to help you :)