# CLLocationManager requestLocation isn't calling didUpdateLocations

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-location

I am trying to get current user location with `[self.locationManager requestLocation]` but for some reason, the delegate method `locationManager: didUpdateLocations:` isn't being called.

I'm calling `requestLocation` from a `UIButton` (`IBOutlet`) handler.

Any idea why?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you set `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in your `Info.plist` file?

Comment: Just `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

Comment: Try setting the other one too.

Comment: Have you enabled the app to receive location information in iOS Settings?  'Allow this app to receive location information .. ' etc

Comment: are you added the `locationManager.delegate = self;`  in your current class

Comment: see this once https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LocationBestPractices.html

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on info.plist open as --> source code add the following code into `<dict>...</dict>`
`<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>App would like to use your location.</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>I need Location</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>App would like to use your location.</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>`

import

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

Then into viewcontroller.h add CLLocationManagerDelegate 
in viewcontroller.m file add this method.

```
-(void)getCurrentLocation{
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Then call the CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manage
didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
CLLocation *currentAction = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
CLLocation *crnLoc = [locations lastObject];

[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;

CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
NSDate* eventDate = location.timestamp;
NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
if (abs(howRecent) < 15.0) {
    // If the event is recent, do something with it.
    NSLog(@"latitude~~~: %+.8f, longitude~~~: %+.8f\n",
          location.coordinate.latitude,
          location.coordinate.longitude);
    self.latitudeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", 
    crnLoc.coordinate.latitude];
    self.longitudeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", 
      crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];
}
self.latitudeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",
crnLoc.coordinate.latitude];
self.longitudeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",
crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];


[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentAction
completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!(error))
     {
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

         NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary
    valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"]
    componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
    NSString *Address = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:locatedAt];
         NSLog(@"Adress %@",Address);
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"\n Current Location Not Detected \n");
         return;
     }
 }];
 }
```

Hope this code Help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9474095/386738).

If you are creating your `CLLocationManager` instance as a function-level instance, it will be dealocated at some point after the function finished (probably before the delegate is called). If you create it as class-level instance instead, the delegate will be called, since the `CLLocationManager` instance will still exist.