# CLLocationManager - Authorization prompt goes away?

Tags: ios, swift, class, cllocationmanager

i try to build a locationHelper-class for handling methods that use CLLocation so that i dont have to rewrite them in every view controller. My LocationHelper class has a Method checkStatus() to check wether the user has already granted the auth for using his location or not. But if i call the method and the user hasnt granted the permission, the prompt comes but goes away like 2 seconds after it comes. I think the problem comes with the implementation of the class, because if i write the code within my ViewController, the prompt stays till the user has made a decission.
My LocationHelper.swift:

```
    import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationHelper: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var delegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate!
    override init(){
        super.init()
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    func requestPermission() -> Void {
        self.locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    //func getLocationInstance() -> CLLocationManager {
    //    return self.locationManager?
    //}
    func checkStatus() -> Void {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .notDetermined:
            // Request when-in-use authorization initially
            print("not determined")
            locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        case .restricted, .denied:
            // Disable location features
            print("status: fail")

        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            // Enable basic location features
            print("in use")


        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("always")
        }
    }

}
```

My ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class LiveDataViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.12, green: 0.67, blue: 0.478, alpha: 1)
        let locHelp = LocationHelper()
        locHelp.checkStatus()


        //locHelp LocationHelper = LocationHelper()
        //locHelp.requestPermission()

    }
```

I would be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you inheriting from `NSObject`? In Swift classes don't have to inherit from a base class, so unless you need some `NSObject` specific functionality, don't inherit from it. Moreover, declaring `locationManager` as an implicitly unwrapped optional makes no sense, simply declare it as `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()`. There's also no need for the delegate to be stored as a variable, since you don't even assign a value to it, `locationManager.delegate = self` is sufficient.

Comment: I think you should check this once

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9474095/9130596

Comment: try to add these two lines of code

let locHelp = LocationHelper()  
locHelp.checkStatus() on viewDidAppear()

Comment: Hi! My new LocationHelper look like this now: https://pastebin.com/cFCFViBN But the prompt goes away after a second. I cant figure out what i have to change that it is a class-level instance variable that it does not close until the class is unloaded.

Comment: @wannabe_informatiker don't post edited code to an external site. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49110087/edit) your question with your updated code instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving a reference to the location helper.

It might be auto released after the view has loaded.

Like so:

```
import UIKit

class LiveDataViewController: UIViewController {

    let locHelp = LocationHelper()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locHelp.checkStatus()
    }
}
```

Comment: @wannabe_informatiker but you can accept his answer instead