# Why in swiftui location popup authorization disappears and reappears quickly?

Tags: swift, swiftui, permissions, cllocationmanager

On my app, I need to get location permission. My application is divided into several components. In the `contentView` file, I call the `locationProvider` class which provides me with the location information. I then pass one of this information into a component that displays the current location or the current heading.

The concern is that when the permissions modal is displayed, it appears and then disappears quickly. I have look at issues on this, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888896/current-location-permission-dialog-disappears-too-quickly). But this one didn't help because it is a bit different;

My `contentView`:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

public extension CGFloat {
  var degreesToRadians: CGFloat { return self * .pi / 180 }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
  @ObservedObject var location: LocationProvider = LocationProvider()
      
  private var windowWidth: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
  
  @State private var heading: CGFloat = .zero
  @State private var city: String = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack() {
                             
      Image("arrow")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(-self.heading)))
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2))
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .onReceive(self.location.heading) { heading in
          self.heading = CGFloat(heading)
        }
      
      Degrees(heading: $heading)
      
      Location(city: $city)
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    .padding(.vertical, 40)
    .onReceive(self.location.city) { city in
      self.city = city
    }
  }
}
```

`LocationProvider` file:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import Combine

public class LocationProvider: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
  
  // Location manager
  private let locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
  
  // Heading
  public let heading = PassthroughSubject<CGFloat, Never>()
  public let city = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
  
  @Published var currentHeading: CGFloat {
    willSet { heading.send(newValue) }
  }
  
  @Published var currentCity: String {
    willSet { city.send(newValue) }
  }
  
  public override init() {
      
    currentHeading = 0
    currentCity = ""
    
    super.init()
    
    //
    // Location manager
    //
    locationManager.delegate = self
    
    self.setup()
  }
  
  private func setup() {
    // Réglage de la préscision
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
  }
  
  //
  //  Location manager - Update Heading
  //  Calcule de l'angle et de la destination
  //
  public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    self.currentHeading = CGFloat(newHeading.magneticHeading)
  }
  
  public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last else { return }
    
    getLocation(from: location) { city, administrativeArea, error in
      guard let city = city, error == nil else { return }
      
      self.currentCity = city
    }
  }
  
  public func getLocation(from location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (_ city: String?, _ administrativeArea: String?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
    
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
      completion(placemarks?.first?.locality, placemarks?.first?.administrativeArea, error)
    }
  }
}
```

`Location` component file:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

struct Location: View {
  
  @Binding var city: String
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack() {
      Text("\(self.city)")
        .font(Font.system(size: 24, weight: .thin, design: .default))
    }
  }
}
```

I know if I declare `@ObservedObject var location: LocationProvider = LocationProvider()` line in the component, the problem does not appear. But is not that I want.

Comment: Not reproducible for me. Is there something that can cause a re-render of `ContentView`? Does it work if you changed `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject`?